# How to solved problem with next.config.js and tmdb API?

Tags: typescript, next.js

i have some problems with code. I develop netflix clone web app, and now i need to do banner with random films photos from tmdb api.
I create .env.local file for my NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY=251f12aad47327cc7ea4862f07acb7***
```

(blur last symbols just here)

Then do movie.ts

```
export const baseUrl = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/'
```

Then do functional for random photos and finally  in tsx

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import { Movie } from '../typings'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { baseUrl } from '../constants/movie'

interface Props {
    netflixOriginals: Movie[]
  }

function Banner({ netflixOriginals }: Props) {
    const [movie, setMovie] = useState<Movie | null>(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        setMovie(
          netflixOriginals[Math.floor(Math.random() * netflixOriginals.length)]
        )
      }, [netflixOriginals])

  return (
    <div>
        <div className='absoute top-0 left-0 h-[95hv] w-screen'>
            <Image
                  fill={true}
                  src={`${baseUrl}${movie?.backdrop_path || movie?.poster_path}`} 
                  alt={'photo'}            
                  />
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Banner
```

And setting next.config.js (how in documentation)

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'image.tmdb.org',
        port: '',
        pathname: 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/',
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

But I always had error >
**Error: Invalid src prop (https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/undefined) on `next/image`, hostname "image.tmdb.org" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`
See more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host**

[Here github repo with all code](https://github.com/Viktor-KL/netflix-clone)

I tried

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: [image.tmdb.org],
  },
}
```

But its for older next versions

Answer (score 0):

finally find solution:

module.exports = {
reactStrictMode: true,
images: {
loader: "default",
minimumCacheTTL: 60,
domains: [
"image.tmdb.org"
],
},
}